# Adding datetime timezone in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm using Rails 4, and Ruby 2.

How do you add a timezone to a DateTime? I want to add the PST timezone to a new DateTime.

I've tried:

```
d = DateTime.strptime('12/21/2012', '%m/%d/%Y')
 => 2012-12-21T00:00:00+00:00 
d.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
 => Thu, 20 Dec 2012 16:00:00 PST -08:00
```

How do I get `Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 PST -08:00`?

Comment: just did a blog post on rails and timezones - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
d = DateTime.strptime('12/21/2012', '%m/%d/%Y').to_time - Time.now.utc_offset
```

If you are using Rails, remember to use `Time.zone` or `DateTime.zone` if it exists. From what I have read, when you use the XX.zone variation you get the config from the Rails app, while if you use it without zone you get the Ruby config, which I think is the system config.